# Navmesh agents trying to go to destroyed objects

Tags: unity, c#, random, navmesh

I am still working on the RTS and have added a system that allows enemies to randomly wander. However, when multiple enemies fight one of my units, they will just clump up Afterwords instead of going back to wandering. Here is the code for their pathfinding.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class Human : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> axolotls;
    Detector detector;
    NavMeshAgent myAgent;
    Vector3 axolotlPosition;
    float lowestDistance = 0;
    public GameObject closestAxolotl;
    Vector3 randomWander;
    Vector3 lastRandomDestination;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        detector = this.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Detector>();
        myAgent = this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        
        axolotls = detector.axolotls;


        
        // Don't put this check inside your for loop:
        // code inside the loop only executes if Count is > 0
        if (axolotls.Count == 0 && myAgent.destination != lastRandomDestination)
        {
            myAgent.SetDestination(randomDestination(randomWander));
        }
        else
        {

            // Initialize our search to the worst possibility: 
            // no target, infinitely far away! (Literally ANYTHING else is better!)
            float lowestScore = Mathf.Infinity;
            GameObject closest = null;

            Vector3 myPosition = transform.position;
            foreach (var axolotl in axolotls)
            {
                // Skip destroyed axolotls (better: make sure they're not in the list!)
                if (axolotl == null) continue;

                // Don't pay for a square root we don't need.
                float score = (axolotl.transform.position - myPosition).sqrMagnitude;

                if (score < lowestScore)
                {
                    closest = axolotl;
                    lowestScore = score;
                }
            }

            // "closest" now contains the nearest axolotl.
            myAgent.SetDestination(closest.transform.position);
            
        }


       
    }
    public void removeAxolotl(GameObject axolotl)
    {
        detector.axolotls.Remove(axolotl);
        if(closestAxolotl == axolotl)
        {
            closestAxolotl = null;
            lowestDistance = 0;
        }
    }
    Vector3 randomDestination(Vector3 randomDestination)
    {
        randomDestination.x = Random.Range(-27, 27);
        randomDestination.z = Random.Range(-27, 27);
        lastRandomDestination = randomDestination;
        Debug.Log("setting destination");
        return randomDestination;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you remove an Axolotl, on which human(s) do you call `removeAxolotl()`?

Comment: Only the human who lands the killing shot. Do you have any suggestions for making it run on all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you remove an Axolotl, on which human(s) do you call removeAxolotl()? –
> DMGregory♦

> Only the human who lands the killing shot. Do you have any suggestions for making it run on all of them? –
> Crystalline787

That's a problem, because this method contains a very important piece of code:

```
closestAxolotl = null;
lowestDistance = 0;
```

All your other humans who were attacking that axolotl don't get their `lowestDistance` variable reset to zero.

Since you only reset this variable to a higher number when its value is exactly zero, and you only change targets to ones whose distance is *lower* than the current `lowestDistance`, if a human was close to an axolotl that died without being the one to land the killing blow, it will refuse to switch targets to *any* axolotl farther away than that now-corpse.

You can make this code much more robust (and more efficient) by not storing `lowestDistance` between frames. Less state to reset!

```
// Don't put this check inside your for loop:
// code inside the loop only executes if Count is > 0
if (axolotls.Count == 0) {
    if (Time.time - lastWanderTime > wanderDuration) { 
       myAgent.SetDestination(randomDestination(randomWander));
       lastWanderTime = Time.time;
    }
} else {

    // Initialize our search to the worst possibility: 
    // no target, infinitely far away! (Literally ANYTHING else is better!)
    float lowestScore = float.positiveInfinity;
    Axolotl closest = null;

    Vector3 myPosition = transform.position;
    foreach (var axolotl in axolotls) {
        // Skip destroyed axolotls (better: make sure they're not in the list!)
        if (axolotl == null) continue;

        // Don't pay for a square root we don't need.
        float score = (axolotl.transform.position - myPosition).sqrMagnitude;

        if (score < lowestScore) {
            closest = axolotl;
            lowestScore = score;
        }
    }

    // "closest" now contains the nearest axolotl.
}
```

There are some other things in your code that don't make sense, like this line, which removes an axolotl from a list, only if it wasn't in that list:

```
if (!axolotls.Contains(closestAxolotl))
{
    axolotls.Remove(closestAxolotl);
    // ...
```

...so I think you should take a thorough proofreading pass through the whole file, or maybe get a friend to do some code review with you, to make sure you don't have more bugs lurking in there.

Comment: Thanks for improved axolotl finding. However, it seems to be constantly assigning each human a new random destination. I tried to check if it is currently going to its random destination but that didn't work.

Comment: You can fix that by enforcing a minimum time spent wandering to one destination before picking a new one to wander to, as shown above.

Comment: Cannot thank you enough.